# Facebook Graph API sharedposts not working

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I am trying to get the name of the persons who shared a particular post. According to facebook's graph api documentation it can be done by :

```
<post_id>/?fields=sharedposts
```

But it just returns back the post id.

Comment: You will only get posts returned that you are allowed to “see” with the access token used and the permissions it includes. If you only get the id of the original post back, then it means there are no shared posts that you can see with the access token.

Comment: I have a FB page. How can I get the shares about the posts in the page? which access token do I need?